# Combining 2 XYZ datasets without overwriting original datasets using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, xyz

I have 2 datasets which I am using ArcGIS Pro to view and edit at the moment.

Basically, dataset 2 is an xyz dataset which contains holes due to being single beam bathymetry data. Dataset 1 is another xyz dataset covering the exact same survey area, only its multibeam bathymetry data.

What I want to achieve is:

1. Keep the single beam data (dataset 2)
2. Draw down the selected multibeam XYZ data (dataset 1) to fill in the areas with no data
3. The output to be the original single beam data with the appropriate multibeam data infilling the initial holes.

I have tried `Merge` but that merges the multibeam xyz on top of the single beam xyz and gives me 6 columns in my attribute table

| X | Y | Z | X | Y | Dens_1050m | Dens_1200m | Dens_1250m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

What I want, is to select one of the single beam densities (Z) values along with their X and Y which fill the holes and combine it with the original multibeam X,Y,Z so that my attribute table looks like:

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |

[image]

Comment: Your datasets...are they points? I couldnt really tell from the pictures.

Comment: @KeaganAllan they are yes! They're single beam and multibeam xyz points

Comment: OK...would you be happy doing some post-processing? You could try two things: 1) Create three new fields (Ensure they are the same datatypes and properties) in both datasets (X_;Y_;Z_), then copy in the original values into the three new fields.. Perform the merge and check that the three new fields make it across. or 2) Do the merge and then create 3 fields and copy the data across into the new fields.

Comment: When you say "xyz dataset" do you mean the XYZ file format used at https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000023381 ?

Comment: @PolyGeo yes thats correct